# Dequeue an item from a set of 1 elements

Tags: linked-list, queue

Given a singly linked list implementation of a queue type with front and rear pointers, when you dequeue an item from a set of 1 elements, do you need to need to set the rear pointer to null?

I'm reading C++ Plus Data Structures by Nell Dale, and in chapter 5.2 he writes in his Dequeue method:

```
if (front == NULL)
  rear == NULL;
```

I'm wondering why is this necessary. The only reason I can think of is the way he implements Enqueue in regards to an empty set:

```
if (rear == NULL)
  front = newNode;
else
  rear->next = newNode;
rear = newNode;
```

But couldn't this condition be changed to `if (front == NULL)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For correct code, you need to maintain the data structure invariants with each operation. The way the original code is written, the invariants look like this:

- A1: `front` points to the first element, if it exists; `NULL` otherwise
- A2: `rear` points to the last element, if it exists; `NULL` otherwise

You're claiming that the invariants could alternatively be these:

- B1: `front` points to the first element, if it exists; `NULL` otherwise
- B2: `rear` points to the last element, if it exists

Now these are similar, but not at all identical. The B invariants don't require any particular value of `rear` when the list is empty. Now you *can* use the B invariants to implement the list, sure, since it admits discrimination between empty and non-empty states, and that's enough to provide correct implementations.

But that doesn't say anything about whether A or B is better in practice. If you use the B invariants, a function to peek at the last element cannot simply return the value of `rear`, since its value can be anything if the queue is empty; you have to test the `front` value first.

```
// for the A2 invariant
return rear ;

// for the B2 invariant
return ( front == NULL ) ? NULL : rear ;
```

This boils down to whether to want to test-and-assign when you dequeue or whether to want to test when you peek at the last element. This is an optimization question, not a correctness one. If you never need to peek at the last element, you can optimize for that.

All this said, this a prime case for the hazards of premature optimization. An extra pointer assignment to `NULL` is almost never going to be a performance problem. What's much more likely to be a problem is introducing a defect during maintenance when someone relies on the A invariants when the existing code is using the B ones. The A invariants are cognitively simpler, because `front` and `rear` are set up analogously, with neither having special behavior. The B invariants might perform better, but at the cost of complexity. Either choice might be better depending on your circumstances.

The Moral Of This Story: **Always** document your invariants.

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of the importance of documenting invariants?

Comment: I would think the answer provides that already. The code snippet provides alternate implementations of a function assuming different invariants. If you write the wrong one, you've written defective code. There are always multiple ways of implementing any given class, but these different ways are (usually) not mutually compatible. If you don't specify invariants, you can easily incorrectly mingle implementation snippets that are correct on their own, but not correct together.